# Making sure Content Script is injected into current tab page without any Page-Refresh after reloading extension from chrome://extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make an extension that scrapes email IDs from the current tab open in the Chrome browser.

After reloading the extension from `chrome://extensions` when I go to the tab where I want to test the extension I'm having to *refresh* the page in order to see the desired results in the console in spite of executing the **Content Script** in **background.js** using `chrome.tabs.executeScript` in order to reinject it into the current tab in the browser.

**Content Script** - Relevant portion

```
var jsonData = scrape();
console.log(jsonData);   //THIS I SEE WITHOUT PAGE REFRESH

chrome.runtime.sendMessage(jsonData, function(response) {
    console.log(response);   //WITHOUT PAGE REFRESH shows undefined, AFTER PAGE REFRESH shows the desired response
});
```

**background.js**

```
var background = {

    injectScript: function() {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "myscript.js"});
        });
    }

};

background.injectScript();
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "emailScraper",
    "version": "1.0",

    "description": "Email Scraping Chrome Extension",
    "icons": {
        "64": "tiki_1.3.png"
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "tiki_1.3.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["js/app/background.js",
                    "js/lib/socket.io/socket.io.js"]
    },

    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*", "https://mail.google.com/*", "https://google.com/*", "file://*/*"],
          "js": ["js/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js", "js/app/myscript.js"],
          "all_frames": false
        }
    ],

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ],

    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' http://localhost:1441/; object-src 'self'"
}
```

I'd also like to add that the **Content Script** is communicating with the **popup.js** of my extension. It sends the list of the email IDs scraped to **popup.js**.**popup.js** on receiving the list sends a response to **Content Script**. This exchange of information takes place only after the current page is refreshed but not otherwise. I wonder why so.

**popup.js**

```
var app = angular.module('emailScraper',[]);

app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    //Fetch URL of current Tab open in Chrome
    chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    }, function(tabs) {
        // and use that tab to fill in out title and url
        var tab = tabs[0];

        $scope.cpUrl = tab.url;
        console.log($scope.cpUrl); //I SEE ONLY THIS LINE WHEN I INSPECT POPUP
    });

    $scope.appLoaded = false;   
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log("Message received: ", request); //I SEE ONLY AFTER PAGE REFRESH IN Inspect Popup BUT NOT IN popup.html view

        $scope.emailList = request;
        $scope.count = Object.keys($scope.emailList).length;
        console.log("Emails found: " + $scope.count); //I SEE ONLY AFTER PAGE REFRESH IN Inspect Popup BUT NOT IN popup.html view
        $scope.appLoaded = true;

        sendResponse({status: "Received JSON data!"});
    });

}]);
```

I appreciate your response.

Comment: Could you post the code of the message listener?

Comment: @Teepeemm You can check the code for the listener in the answer.

Comment: That's not quite how this site works.  Please [edit] the code into your question, and save "Answer" for answers.

Comment: @Teepeemm Sorry about all the trouble. I hope everything's okay now.

Comment: Why there are two same questions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make sure Content Script is injected into current tab without refreshing the current tab after reloading the extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38074550/how-to-make-sure-content-script-is-injected-into-current-tab-without-refreshing)

Comment: @HaibaraAi That question has been deleted a while back.

Comment: Can someone answer my question now please?